# getting a value from the groupby column while using count on another column

Tags: pandas, indexing, count, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to get the `ID` of `occurrence` counts below 20, any ideas?

`df.groupby(['ID']).occurrence.count()`

I tried adding a new column as the count but all values are `NaN`
Thanks

Comment: try df[df.groupby(['ID'])['occurrence'].transform('count') <= 20]. should return a new, reduced dataframe

Comment: Thank you, but still adds nan to the new column

Comment: please post your data to be able to help any further.